# How can I show the rest of a character that has gone slightly outside of UITextView?

Tags: swift, uitextview

I have a UITextView which changes size depending on the text the user inputs (the purple box), which is inside another UIView (the red box).

But when using a handwritten style font like this, the end character sometimes gets cut off at the edge:
[image]

I have tried used `text1.clipsToBounds = false` but that didn't show the edge of the character. Is there a way to show the full character without changing the width of the text view?

Also here is the code I am using to set up the text view:

```
    let text1 = UITextView()
    text1.text = ""
    text1.font = UIFont(name: "Gotcha", size: 27)
    text1.frame = CGRect(x: 10, y: 5, width: 70, height: 50)
    text1.isScrollEnabled = false
    text1.delegate = self
    text1.textAlignment = .center
    text1.isEditable = false
    text1.isSelectable = false
    holdingView.addSubview(text1)
```

The frame then gets updated with this function, and whenever the text is changed:

```
 func adjustTextViewSize(_ textView: UITextView) {

    let maxWidth = 300

    let newSize = textView.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: maxWidth, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude))

    textView.frame = CGRect(x: (textView.frame.minX), y: (textView.frame.minY), width: newSize.width, height: newSize.height)


}
```

Thanks!

**Update:**

I solved this by adding an extra 30px to `newSize.width` for any font that is handwritten:

```
if fontFile?.isHandwritten == true {
   currentView.widthConstraint?.constant = newSize.width + 30
   currentTextHoldingView.widthConstraint?.constant = newSize.width + 30
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm a little unclear what the issue is. You limit the text view's width to 70 and then that turns out not to be wide enough for the text?

Comment: @matt sorry for the confusion, i should have added that the text view changes depending on what is typed into it, so the value 70 is just a temporary starting point - i have edited the question to reflect this. (Also the screenshot is an example of the word Iceland typed in)

Comment: Okay but what you’re doing is not the correct way to answer the question “how wide would this text view need to be to display this text in this font?”

Answer (score 0):

call this function for get height according to string length

```
extension String {
func height(withConstrainedWidth width: CGFloat, font: UIFont) -> CGFloat {
        let constraintRect = CGSize(width: width, height: .greatestFiniteMagnitude)
        let boundingBox = self.boundingRect(with: constraintRect, options: .usesLineFragmentOrigin,
                                            attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.font: font], context: nil)
        return ceil(boundingBox.height)
    }
}
```

Comment: I think the problem here is the width, not the height